# s3: streaming file(s) with embedded ':' in title

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

For various historical reasons Im presented with a series of files on **s3** that have times in the title represented as 'HH:MM:SS' (along with other characters). The file names are coming to me via **SQS** along with other files that don't have these characters.

I can read in the files that *don't* contain the ':' character just fine but am not having success with those that do. I've tried various UUEncode/Decode processes but everything gives me this error:

```
Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon S3, 
but was rejected with an error response for some reason.

Error Message: The specified key does not exist. 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey;
```

I'm wondering if there is some way to encode the key such that the file(s) can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation indicates that the colon character is among those that may need special handling (see the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)):

> The following characters in a key name may require additional code
>   handling and will likely need to be URL encoded or referenced as HEX.

According to [this list](http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html), the colon character's hex value is `%3A`.

In other words, replace your ":" characters with "%3A" when you specify the key and it ought to just work.